# How to suppress the google calender API flow output Python3

Tags: python-3.x, google-calendar-api, gnome-terminal

I would like to know how to suppress the Google flow output to make my output more clean.

Here is the Quickstart.py code:

```
    creds =None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        first_time_login = False
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)


    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        first_time_login = True
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())

        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    # Building the resource Calendar
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
```

When you run this code you get the below output on terminal:

Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=504506216880-4sanqellgo5ovampvrngut6q4e4pr09a.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A46171%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar&state=J7Id4IqIKyER5hykiGhfRcL9HZVejs&access_type=offline

I want there to be no output at all when I run the above code.

Please get the quickstart.py on google calender API or follow this link if it helps:

https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python

Comment: I recommend you to go through google api tutorials if you haven't gone through one.

Comment: what do you mean by supressing the google flow output?

Comment: Yes I mean the the google flow output

Comment: Did you manage to do it? Are there any updates on it?

Comment: I tried to use:

import sys
import io
#You suppress here:
        suppress_text = io.StringIO()
        sys.stdout = suppress_text

Comment: I used the one of the answers to the "Suppress output in unittests" stackoverflow question but it suppressed everything so that didnt work

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done since the authorization flow in the quick-start is designed for a command-line application as mentioned on the quick-start [Notes](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python#notes):

> The authorization flow in this example is designed for a command-line application. For information on how to perform authorization in a web application, [see Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications.](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)

Comment: The best solution for this is to turn off the output for that specific section of the code, then it will just launch to the OAuth 2.0 google account verification on your browser without printing out https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=504506216880-4sanqellgo5ovampvrngut6q4e4pr09a.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A46171%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar&state=J7Id4IqIKyER5hykiGhfRcL9HZVejs&access_type=offline